# Vue v-for with range and ternary class operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, conditional-operator, v-for

I have following code

```
<div class="tabs-container-block">
    <div v-for="n in tabs.length" :class="n-1 === showTab ? 'tab-title active-title' : 'tab-title'"> {{ tabs[n-1].TabTitle }}</div>   
  </div>
  `, 
  data() {
    return {
      showTab: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      }
    }
  },
```

Im trying to use the 'n' value from v-for and ternary operator to switch style classes.

Currently it is not working, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: tabs.length is likely a number. It's a mistake to iterate over it. Probably should be `v-for=(tab, index) in tabs"`

Comment: @EstusFlask im pretty sure thats not an issue, im using v-for with range like for loop with start and end numbers, this is from vue docs <span v-for="n in 10">{{ n }}</span> and this works ok. Im just not getting style classes like I want them to

Comment: I see. Forgot about that. Any way, it's more practical the way described above. `showTab` is declared like a prop, I guess it shouldn't be in `data`

Comment: That was my mistake!!! I confused it with prop and defined it like prop, while actually I wanted to just say showTab = 0; now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showTab` is object , maybe you confuse it with props:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      showTab: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      },
      tabs: [{TabTitle: 'aaa'},{TabTitle: 'bbb'},{TabTitle: 'ccc'}]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tab-title {
  color: green;
}

.active-title {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="tabs-container-block">
    <div v-for="n in tabs.length" :class="n-1 === showTab.default ? 'tab-title active-title' : 'tab-title'"> {{ tabs[n-1].TabTitle }}</div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like exactly the case, "maybe you confuse it with props". Not shown in the code yet